# Pandas: Sum of first N non-missing values per row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'd like to efficiently sum the first N non-missing values of a pandas DataFrame.

For example, if I had dataframe like this:

```
"df"

sid   1900  1899  332   855   1285  1413      1063  1768  2320      1117
bid                                                                     
309  -0.02 -0.03 -0.03 -0.02   NaN -0.01  9.81e-04 -0.02 -0.02  1.25e-02
470  -0.02 -0.04   NaN -0.02 -0.04 -0.02 -2.48e-02 -0.02 -0.02       NaN
818    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -3.87e-02   NaN   NaN -2.54e-02
1080   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -3.61e-02  0.08   NaN       NaN
1292  0.06  0.08 -0.01 -0.01 -0.04  0.01  4.85e-02   NaN  0.00  2.72e-02
1449 -0.02  0.00   NaN   NaN -0.04   NaN       NaN -0.02 -0.00 -5.85e-04
2253 -0.03 -0.04 -0.04 -0.03   NaN -0.02 -4.12e-02 -0.02 -0.03 -2.51e-02
2441   NaN -0.04 -0.03 -0.02   NaN -0.02 -4.19e-02 -0.02 -0.03 -2.68e-02
```

And I wanted to sum the first 3 non-missing values per row, I could loop over the dataframe as follows:

```
row_sum = np.zeros(len(df))
for i, index in enumerate(df.index):
    row_sum[i]=df.ix[index].dropna()[:3].sum()
```

However, this is not particularly efficient. I'd love a method that was vectorized. I've tried a lot different ways to mask the DataFrame or the underlying array (df.values), but haven't figured out anything that works.

I'm worried that there's something obvious that I'm missing here.

Note: it's okay if the row only has less than N items. I just want at most N per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
at_most=2
df.apply(lambda x: (x[np.isfinite(x)][:at_most]).sum(), axis=1)
```

Comment: This works, is a little faster, and is more elegant. So, thanks. However, to get the row sum, one needs to specify axis=1. What you've written returns column sums.

Comment: Quite right. Actually it is going to be confusing as the `axis=1` can be inside `sum()` or be inside `apply()`, so I edited it to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: For what it's worth this method is slightly faster in my environment than the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's faster, but a more "pandonic" way could look like:

```
def sum_first_n(row,n):
    return row.dropna()[:n].sum()
df.apply(sum_first_n, n=3, axis = 1)
```

This will return a series with the same index as your original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I like this idea, but this returns None for each row for me. Also, should [:3] be [:n]?

Comment: No, this will not work. The reason you get `nan` for each row is that the function is missing `return`. And you are right about the `[:n]` thing.

Comment: You are correct in both cases, extremely sloppy on my part. Fixed.